# Task Execution Framework for VC++?

Tags: c++, frameworks, execution

Does anyone know of a Java ExecutorService equivlent in VC++ 2008? What I want is a framework which I can pass tasks to fixed size thread pool. The framework should manage the thread pool itself (i.e. creation and destruction of threads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vista has a new thread pool API (in addition to existing, rather spartan thread pool API windows has had for a while): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686766%28VS.85%29.aspx . This API is not bound to any specific version of MSVC/VS but of course to use the new stuff you need to have Vista/Server 2008 or better. `QueueUserWorkItem` and `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` may be sufficient for your needs. As Nikola points out, 2010 will have the PPL. .NET also has some nice thread pool apis if you can code against C# or maybe C++/CLI instead of C++.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) supports something like this. Visual Studio 2010 will have [Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434652.aspx).